# How to implement a custom file parser in Google DataFlow for a Google Cloud Storage file

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a custom file format in Google Cloud Storage and I want to read it from Google DataFlow.

I've implemented a Source and a Reader by subclassing FileBasedReader, but then I realized it didn't support reading from Google Cloud Storage (while FileBasedSink actually does...) so I'm not sure what's the best idea to solve that here...

I tried to subclass TextIO but I couldn't reach an end with that as it doesn't seem to be designed to be subclassed.

Any good idea on how to deal with that?

Thanks.

## Update to reflect on the comments

File pattern used: `gs://mybucket/my.json`

Implemented the Source class from FileBasedSource:

```
MessageSource<T> extends FileBasedSource<T>
```

Implemented the Reader class (what I really care about here) from FileBasedReader:

```
MessageReader<T> extends FileBasedReader<T>
```

Process for reading is:

```
MySource source = // instantiate source
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
p.apply(TextIO.Read.from(options.getSource()).named("ReadFileData"))
     .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
```

And the getSource() comes from this command line parameter (verified correct):

```
    --source=gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/my.json \
```

Am I missing anything?

## 2nd UPDATE

While running `source.getEstimatedSizeBytes(options)` it tells me no handler found?

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to find handler for gs://mybucket/my.json
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.IOChannelUtils.getFactory(IOChannelUtils.java:186)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.FileBasedSource.getEstimatedSizeBytes(FileBasedSource.java:182)
at com.etc.TrackingDataPipeline.main(TrackingDataPipeline.java:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I thought the FileBasedSource was supposed to handle GCS?

Comment: Hmm, FileBasedReader is, absolutely, intended to be used with Google Cloud Storage. Could you edit your question to clarify what problems you ran into when using it?

Comment: Hmm... I might have missed it but I couldn't see any reference to GCS in the sources? Regardless, the issue I'm having is the file never gets loaded with no error being triggered. I am not sure how to debug that. I also haven't found any sample using FileBasedReader to do the same thing. I'll try to update the question to reflect that in the light of your comment @jkff

Comment: Yup, please update the question with more details - not much I can do without that. In fact almost all sources, including TextIO, are implemented using FileBasedSource/Reader under the hood.

Comment: @jkff I have updated the issue. Does it help to make things clearer?

Comment: Actually, I just realized I forgot to update that issue, but @jkff you were right. It was indeed working. I had an issue somewhere else in the code and the whole thing was failing silently, but the file did end up being read correctly.

Answer (score 3):

From the stack trace you show in "2nd Update", it looks like you have called `getEstimatedSizeBytes` directly from your `main()` method. This is expected to lead to the error you see.

The standard URL scheme handlers are registered when a pipeline runner is constructed. In your example code, that would happen when you call `Pipeline.create(options)` (this calls `PipelineRunner.fromOptions(options)`, where the standard handlers are registered).

If you want to have the standard URL schemes registered in a context other than running a pipeline, you can explicitly call `IOChannelUtils.registerStandardIOFactories()`. I should note that this is not a supported API, but reaching a bit "under the hood". As such, it may change at any time.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Thanks for the details. I've realized that later on and it was confirmed by Google support. It sadly wasn't related to the root problem though.